# Failed to execute query. Error: String or binary data would be truncated in table xdbo.user_info', column 'uid'

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I have problem inserting values in my SQL server database on Azure, I am getting the following error:

```
Failed to execute query. Error: String or binary data would be truncated in table 'dummy_app.dbo.user_info', column 'uid'. Truncated value: 'u'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

I don't understand where I am wrong, I just created the server, and I am trying to experiment but cant fix this.

```
if not exists (select * from sysobjects where name='user_info' and xtype='U')

    create table user_info (

        uid varchar unique,
        name varchar,
        email varchar

    )

go;
INSERT INTO dbo.user_info(uid, name, email) VALUES('uids', 'name', 'email') go;
```

Creating the table works fine, the only thing that doesn't work is the second command INSERT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that the reason is that you haven't defined a lenght for varchar and it defaults to 1 as length. Therefore your value gets truncated.

Set a varchar length to something like varchar(200) and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the fact that the `CREATE` portion of your procedure for the table doesn't include a length of `varchar`, so you'd have to specify a length such as `varchar(50)` since the default is 1. Refer to the official MS docs in the link, in the remarks.

[docs.miscrosoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current#remarks)

Also, here is the syntax for the `CREATE TABLE` in Azure which might be helpful as well.

[Syntax of Azure CREATE TABLE](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-azure-sql-data-warehouse?view=aps-pdw-2016-au7#syntax)